# Not able to send contact form email with SendGrid on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid

I trying to implement a contact form on Nodejs and express with SendGrid but it's giving me `403 Forbidden` error, but the post request i sent returns `200`. i don't know what i'm doing wrong, please i need a help to fix this.

Here is my whole `route`

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const ContacForm = require('../models/contact_form')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");


router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact_form/new") 
})

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
const output = `
    <p>You have a new Request</p>
    <h3>Contact Details </h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
        <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li> 
    /ul>
<h3>Message</h3>
<li>Request: ${req.body.request}</li>
`;

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
    to: 'chukwumakingley1@gmail.com',
    from: 'chukwumakingley1@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
    html: output,
};

sgMail.send(msg, (error, contact)=> {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.render("contact_form/new")
    }
 });
});
```

and these is the error message response i get on the terminal

```
ResponseError: Forbidden
at node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:105:29
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
code: 403,
message: 'Forbidden',
response: {
headers: {
  server: 'nginx',
  date: 'Sat, 11 Apr 2020 13:15:25 GMT',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '281',
  connection: 'close',
  'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
  'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
  'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas- 
 acl',
  'access-control-max-age': '600',
  'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html'
},
 body: { errors: [Array] }
}
}
```

and here is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="/contact_form">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
  <label>Request</label>
  <textarea  name="request" id="request" placeholder="Enter Your  Prayer Request" cols="30" 
  rows="10"></textarea>
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

NOTE: I'm sending my `SENDGRID_API_KEY` variable and it's coming through

This is the kind of Sendgrid API that i am using

```
Integrate using our Web API or SMTP Relay
```

Answer (score 4):

I just figured it out after taking time to research and read through the documentation.

It happened that I needed to do additional authentication called `Single Sender Verification` etc.

and I changed my code to give me a better understanding of the error

```
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'chukwumakingsley1@gmail.com',
  from: 'chukwumakingsley1@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Hello world',
  text: output
};

sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {
    //Celebrate
    console.log('Email Sent!');
  })    
  .catch(error => {

    //Log friendly error
    console.error(error.toString());
    console.log(output)

    //Extract error msg
    const {message, code, response} = error;

    //Extract response msg
    const {headers, body} = response;
  });
});
```

after changing the code, the error message changed to

```
Forbidden (403)
The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for- 
developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity 
requirements
```

from this error, I read through the error docs on send-grids.

I think the additional authentication was added last month.

Answer (score 0):

Your post request is returning 200 because you call `res.render("contact_form/new")` when there IS an error:

```
if(error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.render("contact_form/new")
}
```

Take a look at the body of the response you get from the SendGrid response. It contains an array of errors that may provide more information on why you're receiving a 403.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the sendgrid from April 6, 2020 changed some criteria for authentication of free tests :(. Now it is necessary to make some configurations.
What solved for me was to follow this tutorial here from them. https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/sender-verification/. Only authorizing a few emails to send requests